# How can I create and start an Intent?

Tags: java, android, usb, point-of-sale, thermal-printer

I was wondering how I can create and start an intent using this:

"qsrtech.posprintdriver/.printservice"

I downloaded the POS Printer Driver (ESC) app (which is the app I am trying to access).

I tried this:

```
        String PrintPage = "qsrtech.posprintdriver/.printservice";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);             
        intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(PrintPage));             
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );             
        startActivity(intent);
```

However, I get an error saying:
"No activity found to handle this intent"

I was wondering if there is anything I can do to access this intent? The thing is that I'm not sure if I'm accessing an activity or a background service (probably an intent service?) from a different app.

Here is the link that explains more about this intent.
http://www.qsrtechnologies.com/aboutposdriver.html

Comment: try `"qsrtech.posprintdriver/qsrtech.posprintdriver.printservice"` as your component string to unflatten. Also it looks like you aren't adding any data, so I doubt anything will get printed, you'll probably want to include the `putExtra("Data", somethingToPrint)`

Comment: Thanks FoamyGuy for your quick response. So your answer helped me get rid of the "No Activity found to handle this intent" error. However, not I have an "Unable to find explicit class, have you declared this activity in your androidmanifest.xml?" error.

I added:

<activity android:name="qsrtech.posprintdriver.printservice"</activity> 

to my androidmanifest.xml file. I don't have this Java class in my project (because I'm assuming that it's in another app). Any suggestions on how I can solve this issue? Thanks again.

Comment: You could try the solutions posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940456/code-to-launch-external-app-explicitly

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("Data", "Test printer\n\n");
sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("qsrtech.posprintdriver","qsrtech.posprintdriver.printservice"));
startService(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("Data", "Test printer\n\n");
sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("qsrtech.posprintdriver","qsrtech.posprintdriver.printservice"));
startService(sendIntent);
```

Worked like a charm here.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to to confirm that the mentioned code works. Anyway I was only could print  characters and not ESC code. I guess  because the "ESC POS Android Driver" is not free and must be purchased. is it ?