# Return back to the previous application

Tags: android

Scenario:

1. I'm having one application called A. By pressing the button in A then Application B should be launched.
2. In application B I want to design one button on top left corner. Title of the button is back to the application A.
3. By pressing the button in Application B the screen should return back to the application A.

For example:
If I am using Facebook I should have one button to launch whatsapp. In case of launching whatsapp from Facebook, I should have one button on top left of whatsapp title to go back to Facebook by pressing that button. I need to get back to the Facebook.

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940456/code-to-launch-external-app-explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` on Application B.

Application A is still open and when Application B closes, Application A will show again.

Or you could call Application A, and then `finish()` Application B, to ensure that action always returns to A.

Comment: Right brother. but i need back button on application B. by pressing that button only i have to return back to application A.

Comment: launch application A without closing B, is that what you mean? B remains open, but A shows?

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
func deleteItem(byId: Int, completion: Result<Void,Error>) -> ());

foo.deleteItem(byId: 1) { result in
   swith result {
      case success():
         // Success case
         handleSuccess(item)
      case let failure(error):
         // Error case
         handleError(error!)
   }
}
```

Comment: i can't even guess this.

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`finish ();`
for the button in java.It will kill App B automatically and you will switch back to App A

Comment: Thanks..! And please try to understand my question.

Comment: or you can add another intent there